# Check if in DAG exist nodes with specific distance

Tags: algorithm, tree, distance, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a directed acyclic graph with one end node and many start nodes. In this graph each node can be junction, pier or both. Each edge have specific distance.
I have two thinks to do.

1. Determine if there is two piers (accessible in direction of graph) with total distance of `d` (= small int)
2. Determine if there is two piers with total distance of `d`. In this case direction doesn't matter

I will be grateful for any idea of effective algorithm.

Comment: Are the edge distances small integers too?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Yes

Comment: When you say "with total distance of `d`" do you mean that there exists a path of length exactly `d`, that the shortest path should have length exactly `d`, or something else?

Comment: I have to check if there is any path (without repeating edges) of length exactly `d`. So output should be boolean.